# get property types at runtime

Tags: java, generics, reflection, groovy, type-erasure

I have a Groovy class such as

```
class User {
    List<Foo> someFoos = new ArrayList<Foo>()
    List<Bar> someBars = new ArrayList<Bar>()    
}
```

I can iterate over these properties at runtime using

```
def user = new User()
List<MetaProperty> setProperties = user.metaClass.properties.findAll {MetaProperty property ->
    property.name.startsWith('some')
}
```

If I inspect the type of each of these properties `Set` is returned

```
setProperties.each {MetaProperty setProperty -> 
    assert setProperty.type == Set    
}
```

Is there any way at runtime I can get the generic type parameter (`Foo` and `Bar`) for each of these properties?

I strongly suspect I cannot due to type erasure, but If someone could confirm my suspicions, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: those aren't properties, those are fields.

Comment: @Daniel that's a Groovy class, so they're properties

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can. These are field definitions and they retain their type definitions at runtime. I'll give you the java code, you can also use it in groovy (I don't know a groovy-specific solution)

```
Field[] fields = User.class.getDeclaredFields();
for (Field field : fields) {
    ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) field.getGenericType();
    Type concreteType = pt.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
}
```

Comment: In the case I've mentioned above, should it be safe to downcast from Type to Class. If not, is there another was I can convert the Type to a Class?

Comment: Works like a charm - take a bow. Maybe some day I will understand what generic type information is erased at runtime